# Intercept Auth redirect from Electron and Angular and handle it in the same window

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, electron, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have an Angular 9 application that is doing basic authentication against Azure Active Directory, using msal.js
This is working with no issues.

When trying to run my Angular app wrapped with Electron in the following scenario:

1. user clicks login button
2. ms login window opens
3. user enters password and clicks next.

**Expected**:
main page is refreshed/reloaded with user authenticated (same Electron window)

**Actual**:
another window is opening with no authentication.

I've tried to intercept all kinds of redirect/navigate using the webContents objects in main.js without success.
Looking for some help.

Comment: Does it open a popup?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?